# How to add a CSV in the ClickHouse JDBC library

Tags: jdbc, clickhouse

This is in a Java project with the ClickHouse JDBC library:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
   <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>0.3.2-patch11</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to try to insert a CSV through a:

```java
String url = "jdbc:ch://localhost";

ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url, new Properties());

ClickHouseConnection conn = dataSource.getConnection("default", "password");

ClickHousePreparedStatement clickHousePreparedStatement = (ClickHousePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table FORMAT CSV < ?");
```

I have tried to simulate something like this with:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table FORMAT CSV < ?");
ps.setString(1, "simulated csv rows separated with commas");
```

It works, but it is not what I'm looking for. I want to know if the library has something specific, the documentation I have not found anything.

How can I attach a CSV in the ClickHouse JDBC library?

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/1001

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/909

Comment: Do you have CSV as a java stream or as a file? Or how are you going to bake CSV?

Comment: _"but it is not what I'm looking for"_, so exactly *what* are you looking for instead?

Comment: @DennyCrane Thanks, this solution works for me and this is what I'm looking for https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/1001#issuecomment-1186842578

Answer (score 0):

A viable approach for loading CSV data files into a ClickHouse database is to use the Clickhouse Java client. The Maven dependency is called `clickhouse-client` and found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.clickhouse/clickhouse-client).

The documentation for the Java client is found [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/java#java-client) and is not particularly extensive. See a Java example below which includes the ability specify custom settings, including skipping the first line (headers) of the CSV file and using comma as value delimiter.

```java
// Connect to the ClickHouse server with username/password authentication

ClickHouseNode server = ClickHouseNode.builder()
    .host( "127.0.0.1" )
    .port( ClickHouseProtocol.HTTP )
    .database( "mydatabase" )
    .credentials( ClickHouseCredentials
        .fromUserAndPassword( "username", "password" ) )
    .build();

// Create a CSV file reference

ClickHouseFile file = ClickHouseFile.of( 
    "/path/to/file.csv", ClickHouseCompression.NONE, ClickHouseFormat.CSV );

// Create a client

ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance( server.getProtocol() );

// Specify settings, load data to the specified table and wait for completion

client.write( server )
    .set( "input_format_csv_skip_first_lines", "1" )
    .set( "format_csv_delimiter", "," )
    .table( "mytable" )
    .data( file )
    .executeAndWait();
```